# Output pyLDAvis topic keywords with chosen lambda

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling, topicmodels, pyldavis

I used PyLDAvis visualize LDiA model outputs and by playing around lambda I found key word chosen for each topic can be very interpretable under certain lambda value than others. I wonder if there is a easy way to output key words under certain lambda value for each topic. Currently I can only output keywords from the trained LDiA model directly, which has no lambda involved, and often the top selected key words are not very interpretable for the specific topic.